# Read file using regex Perl

Tags: regex, perl, file

I have a configuration file name camera.start . The configuration looks like this :

```
video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 -vcodec
```

My question is, how can we read the **/dev/video0** only in Regex? But know this that the value **/dev/video0** is always changing. So i cannot read that file using **[characters]** modifiers. Any suggestion on how to read this configuration file using regex? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried splitting on spaces and retrieving the third element? Would that solve your question?

Comment: Can you show me how? Seriously im weak with regex. :( @Robin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for regex, just split on a space character:

```
my $data = 'video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 -vcodec';

my @values = split(' ', $data);

print @values[2];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
my $str = 'video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 -vcodec';

my $dev = (split ' ', $str)[2];

print $dev;
```

Comment: Your answer the same as the above. Thanks @Miller I'll try it first

Answer (score 2):

The string can be parsed by splitting on ' ' caracter.

But if you still want a regex, here you are

```
my $str = "video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 -vcodec";
($i) = ($str =~ m/video4linux2 -i (\S+) -vcodec/);

print "$i\n";  # '/dev/video0'
```

Comment: Oh my god, so many answer. You all are correct. I dont know who i want to upvote. Thanks all @user3165879